# CSS line-height not working

Tags: css

I have this div that I am trying to apply line-height like so...

```
.social {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 93px;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: 190px;
}
```

but the `.social` class won't down, whatever is inside the div stays at the top...here is the html..

```
<div class="social">
     <ul>
          <li class="facebook">
               <a href="http://www.facebook.com/SurfTheCurve" target="_blank"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="twitter">
               <a href="https://twitter.com/SurfCurveTutor" target="_blank"></a>
          </li>
          <li class="email">
               <a href="mailto:info@surfthecurve.ca?subject=Website Enquiry" target="_blank"></a>
          </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

Here is some other CSS

```
.social ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}

.social li {
    float: left;
}

.social ul .facebook a {
    background-image: url("images/facebook.png");
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
}

.social ul .twitter a {
    background-image: url("images/twitter.png");
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
}

.social ul .email a {
    background-image: url("images/email.png");
    background-position: right center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 35px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: What do you mean by "[go] down"? You are floating LI's. You may be getting yourself into some DIV clearing issue there… But please explain better what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`line-height` requires text (otherwise there's no line!) but the HTML you've provided doesn't have any text, it's all just empty `<a>` elements.

I made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7vcmC/ (I had to change the color settings) but I guess that's the effect you're after?

Comment: You can't say definitively that users don't want links to open in new tabs. I very much appreciate it when links inside of gmail don't navigate me away from gmail. I think it depends on that application.

Comment: I add `line-height` for `input` buttons but it didn't applying on it in FF. Why is that so?

Comment: This helped me.  The answer I needed: Put the line-height on the "a" tag if you want the link's height changed.  At least for me (Firefox) just styling the container div doesn't affect the link.